# Appium cannot convert webelement list to arraylist of hashmap

Tags: android, testing, appium

I wants to show data from sqlite db in listview .
I am getting data in a arraylist format(ArrayList>).So i want that arraylist values to display in listview.
here **list** is my listview id.

```
 driver.findElement(By.id("com.example.project:id/list"));
```

I searched in google and got this

```
List<WebElement> list =  driver.findElement(By.id("com.example.project:id/list"));
```

But i want like this

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> list = driver.findElement(By.id("com.example.project:id/list"));
```

But i am getting compile time error like 
**appium getting error cannot covert ArrayList> to List**

So in
Please can anyone help me!

Answer (score 0):

driver.findElement will return you a WebElement (the element with your id).

If your id is applied to several elements then you want to use (notice the extra s):

```
List list =  driver.findElements(By.id("yourId"));
```

If you really want to force a cast to List < WebElement > you can do:

```
List<WebElement> list =  (List<WebElement>)(List) driver.findElements(By.id("yourId"));
```

and add  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") for the warning to stop appearing about that unchecked cast

For the ArrayList < HashMap < String, Object > >, I have no idea what you trying to place in String and in Object